# Jquery Confirmation samples

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to have more samples regarding the jquery confirmation box.

I have learned how to show the confirmation dialogue box through the below example:

http://www.webstuffshare.com/2010/03/jquery-plugin-jconfirmaction/

But, I need more colorful and attractive samples, can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSend").click(function (e) {
            var result = window.confirm('Are you sure?');
            if (result == false) {
                e.preventDefault();
            };
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

visit the following websites. you will find so many confirmation box developed by jquery plugin library.

http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take a look at [jQuery UI's dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation). jQuery UI is jQuery's official user interface library. So you're sure to avoid [The Bathroom Wall of Code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/the-bathroom-wall-of-code.html) :)

Also; the documentation and community around this library is huge. So if you we're to get stuck; you are sure to get help.

Comment: Hello friend,

I need more clear examples, I am having a delete link in the table and would like to show the confirmation box

Answer (score 0):

Try this example...

In your view page where the delete button is present, type this code..

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Remove this?">
    <p align="justify"> 
         <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
         This will be permanently deleted in our system and cannot be recovered. Do you want to continue?
    </p>
</div>
```

Trigger example of delete button (put this in your js file):

```
$("#deletebutton").click(function() {
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
}

// jquery-ui confirm dialog box
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   resizable: false,
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
        'Remove': function() { // remove what you want to remove
               // do something here
         },
         Cancel: function() {
               $(this).dialog('close');
         }
   }
});
```

Note: Do not forget to include jquery script and jquery-ui plugin script in your header file. This will not work without this files.

You can download the jquery-ui plugin [here](http://jqueryui.com/).

If you have further questions, just post comments. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [jAlerts](http://beckelman.net/2008/12/30/jquery-alert-dialogs/) and demo [here](http://beckelman.net/demo/jquery-alert-dialogs/)

I've been using it for quite a long time and happy with it. You can customize the way you want and works cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery confirmation dialogs must not be that hard to make, 
i have made a confirmation plugin myself, [jquery-confirm](https://github.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm) that supports modern features.

First of all you must think of how to initialize your confirm. 
directly `pluginname({title: 'amazing'});` 
or binding to a element `$('.e').pluginname({title:'amazing'})`

Then where do u append the plugins HTML content.
You can provide the option to the user, and set it to `$('body')`

Opening and closing your confirm matters too,
can be done by 
JS or CSS.
for example your html markup is

`<div class="myplugin-container">The confirmation content goes here</div>` 
You set a CSS rule

```
.myplugin-container{
   visibility: hidden;
   transition: all .4s; //transition last for .4s.
   transform: scale(0); //by default the modal is scaled to 0.
}
.myplugin-container.show{
   visibility: visible;
   transform: scale(1);
}
```

The moment you load your confirmation plugin's html in the DOM it will be hidden because of the above rules.
and in you JS code you add a class to your `.myplugin-container` 

`$('.myplugin-container').addClass('show')` 
At this point your confirmation dialog will have a opening animation.
that goes from Smaller to normal.