# JQuery confirm dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, confirm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Yes or No confirm box using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519861/yes-or-no-confirm-box-using-jquery)

I see a lot of examples here about replacements for jQuerys standard confirm dialog but don't understand any of them.

If I want to pop-up a confirm dialog using jQuery or jQueryUI. How can i do it and retrieve what button the user clicked ?

Surely there must be a simple way to set up a confirm dialog like an `alert("Something!");` command.

Add two buttons to it and set a call back function on `yes` or `no` ?

Comment: Could you provide us a link to one of these examples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383546/jquery-confirmation-samples

Comment: I have tried tweaking this one to suit my needs but can't get it working

Comment: Check out this jQuery plugin: http://myclabs.github.com/jquery.confirm/

Comment: Pop-up confirm dialog with jQuery only (no jQueryUI needed) http://jsfiddle.net/B92M5/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this one

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
  .html('<div><h6>Yes or No?</h6></div>')
  .dialog({
      modal: true, title: 'message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
      width: 'auto', resizable: false,
      buttons: {
          Yes: function () {
              doFunctionForYes();
              $(this).dialog("close");
          },
          No: function () {
              doFunctionForNo();
              $(this).dialog("close");
          }
      },
      close: function (event, ui) {
          $(this).remove();
      }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3d7QC/1032/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18474005/1876355

Comment: could you explain how to call doFunctionForYes if it is in c#?

Comment: c# has no control here, only with JavaScript this works

Comment: This answer uses jQueryUI library. This needs to be added to on top of jQuery standard library. see http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519861/yes-or-no-confirm-box-using-jquery/10753619#10753619

Comment: @sjd C# runs on the server and JavaScript runs on the browser. To call a C# function from JavaScript you need to make a call to the server, using something like ajax

Answer (score 13):

You can use jQuery UI and do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/nvZc4/)

**Html:**

```
<button id="callConfirm">Confirm!</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required">
  Are you sure about this?
</div>​
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   modal: true,
   buttons : {
        "Confirm" : function() {
            alert("You have confirmed!");            
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

$("#callConfirm").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

​

Comment: Hi,  When I try this the string "Are you sure about this"  just appears in my browser.  I have put the javascript you added into my ready method for the page but nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: @user965895: did you try the jsFiddle? It must work. Could you, please, include your script in your question so we can check?

Comment: @user965895: Don't forget you have to include jQuery UI scripts and CSS.

Comment: Can't make the code work. It also just appears on my browser as plain text. Clicking the button does nothing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767749/jquery-confirmation-not-working

Comment: @ladiesman1792: I've tried it with a few browser (Chrome, FF, Edge) and it does work.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the [official JQueryUI implementation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) (not jQuery only) :  ?

Comment: `JQuery UI` implementation, JQuery as default does not include the UI.

Comment: Indeed it does not. But finding the required libraries is neither difficult nor onerous.